# LetsEncrypt Certbot rejects DNS TXT record for wildcard Certificate

Tags: ssl, dns, certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

**Task**:
I want to create a wildcard certificate for both *.example.com and example.com in one go, using the DNS challenge method provided by the LetsEncrypt Certbot.

**Reproduce**:
When trying to obtain the certificate files neccessary to set up my SSL-Certificate, I run into a catch22-situation with the LetsEncrypt Certbot.

I call the certbot command with these parameters

```
certbot certonly --agree-tos --manual --preferred-challenges dns --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d "*.example.com,example.com"
```

and am requested to enter two DNS TXT records in the response from the command afterwards.

So far, so good. But if I enter the two requested DNS TXT records for the given domains as requested by the certbot command, I receive an error message:

> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: example.com    Type:   unauthorized    Detail: Incorrect
>   TXT record    "[authentication snippet for example.com]" found at
>   _acme-challenge.example.com
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address.

**Problem**: The Certbot does not accept the very same DNS TXT records is has just prompted me to set.

It seems that the Certbot is not able to cope with the fact that I am trying to request the certificate for both "*.example.com" and "example.com" at once, treating them as if they were belonging to two different domain realms and not accepting the two TXT records as expected.

Comment: Did you check if the entries by running `host -t txt _acme-challenge.example.com`

Comment: 'Incorrect TXT record ""' looks more like the entry was not added to the DNS at all... (empty string as a TXT record data)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: The authentication snipped was only truncated in my stackoverflow-post. It was correctly reflected in the original message from the LetsEncrypt-Bot.

Comment: It turned out that this error indeed occurred due to a DNS refresh lag caused by the domain provider. @l0w_skilled's response helped me figure out that the actual TXT-records I have entered took a few minutes to be set by the domain-service provider, even though its TTL was set to 60 seconds. Thanks for the reply. Problem solved!

Comment: "The authentication snipped was only truncated in my stackoverflow-post. " which shows the perils of bad obfuscation... TXT records are in the DNS hence public. Disclosing them has no adverse consequence, so by removing them altogether and making it look like as if you did not get any valid DNS reply in fact was just misleading to anyone wanting to help and making them loose time...

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that this error indeed occurred due to a DNS refresh lag caused by the domain provider. @low_skilled's response helped me figure out that the actual TXT-records I have entered took a few minutes to be set by the domain-service provider, even though its TTL was set to 60 seconds. Thanks for the reply. Problem solved!

Comment: The TTL has no bearing on the amount of time the provider needs to put your new data, given through some kind of website or API, into its zonefile. The TTL starts to apply after the record exist in the DNS.

Comment: Anyother option without adding txt record? If i add txt record, it takes time to get updated. While waiting for the txt record to go live, the ssh connection fails. Next time i run certbot it gives another txt record. Don't they know that adding dns entries will take time?

Answer (score 1):

I discover that have to be created just **one** record TXT (_acme-challenge.*) with **two** values (hash given by certbot) separated by **line**. After run certbot, remember to restart your webserver.

I think depends on your DNS server to setup this. I did it in Route 53 - AWS and this fix this problem.

Obs: Considering wait some seconds (+30) after change your records.

I know you fix your problem, but I think it can help someone to learn how certbot works.